# update query doesnt work oracle and jsp

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Everybody hi

my update query doesnt work. and dont have any exception
My code;

```
String sorgu = "update KISI set unvani=?, gorevi=?,"
                    + "firma=?,adres=?,tel=?,"
                            + "fax=?,gsm=?,mail=?,"
                                    + "web=? where kisi_id=?";

            try {
                System.out.println("get adressss "+guncelleForm.getAdres());
                System.out.println("get ünvan "+guncelleForm.getUnvani());
                conn = VTU.baglantiAl();
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sorgu);
                pst.setString(1, guncelleForm.getUnvani());
                pst.setString(2, guncelleForm.getGorevi());
                pst.setString(3, guncelleForm.getFirma());
                pst.setString(4, guncelleForm.getAdres());
                pst.setString(5, guncelleForm.getTel());
                pst.setString(6, guncelleForm.getFax());
                pst.setString(7, guncelleForm.getGsm());
                pst.setString(8, guncelleForm.getMail());
                pst.setString(9, guncelleForm.getWeb());
                pst.setString(10, guncelleForm.getId());

                pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

what is the problem ı dont understand. I use oracle. ı can see value with println() it is nor null. guncelleForm has get/set only 
thank you for everything

Comment: Start your parameter count with 0. It is probably your problem. `pst.setString(0, .......`

Comment: Try to run your formed Sql query in Oracle first then try in code.It may be Query error.

Comment: Jani ı did it. and query was running

Comment: Is your connection set to autocommit?

Comment: Jorge if you ask the VTU class yes it is

Comment: Is there any exception caught in the catch block? If yes: what does it say? Try `conn.commit();` after `pst.executeUpdate();`.

Comment: Trinimon there isnt any exception caught in the catch block

Comment: @Really: is `guncelleForm.getId()` equal to one of the `kisi_id`'s in `KISI`? May be your instance `guncelleForm` isn't initialized as intended. Keep in mind that `= NULL` (comparison to `NULL`) is always false!

Comment: oh my god you are right Triniom. Yes my id is null. So sorry

Comment: No prob - I'm happy to help. I posted my hint as an answer - may be it will help someone else in future as well.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: no, that's wrong. Parameter indexes in JDBC start with `1` not with `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take care that `guncelleForm.getId()` is equal to one of the `kisi_id`'s in `KISI`? May be your instance `guncelleForm` isn't initialized as intended.

Keep in mind that `= NULL` (comparison to `NULL`) is always false!

Answer (score 0):

Do 3 things

1. Check your database credentials, is posible you are executing the query in a different enviroment.
2. Show the trace in the catch with ex.printStackTrace().
3. Verify is your code execution finish with a trace after the executeUpdate().